# Constant factor of an array

Tags: algorithm-analysis, data-structures, amortized-analysis

In *Elements of Programming Interviews in Python* by Aziz, Lee and Prakash, they state on page 41:

> Insertion into a full array can be handled by resizing, i.e.,
>   allocating a new array with additional memory and copying over the
>   entries from the original array. This increases the worst-case time of
>   insertion, but if the new array has, for example, a constant factor
>   larger than the original array, the average time for insertion is
>   constant since resizing is infrequent.

I grasp the concept of amortization that seems to be implied here, yet they seem to imply that in other cases, a newly allocated array could possess a constant factor *smaller* than the original array. Is that so? What does "constant factor" mean in this particular context? I'm having trouble understanding what's being said here.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's probably a typo or poor wording -- in the quote, "has" should be "is".

Answer (score 3):

This approach suggest to pick any constant factor $k>1$ and use that whenever one needs to reallocate the array. That is, each time the array becomes full and has $n$ elements, a new array of size $k\cdot n$ is allocated, and data is copied from the old array.

It is important here to multiply the size by a constant $k$ rather than, say, adding a fixed amount of additional entries (moving from $n$ to $n+k$) to achieve a better amortized complexity.